# SAS string with "&xxx="

Tags: sas

I would like to do web scrape while there is error occur when i define the filename for the http link.

```
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference F not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference E not resolved.
2016  filename in url
2016! 'http://finance.yahoo.com:80/d/quotes.txt?s=YHOO+IBM+HPQ&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.txt';
```

THanks for your attention

Comment: A warning isn't an error. SAS is telling you that your address contains what it thinks is a macro variable (&e). If you can use single quotes around the URL instead or a quoting function?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are actually using here?